# Byte array to string gives "???"

Tags: java, string, byte, arrays, steganography

So I am trying to write a [steganography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography) program in java.

Here is what I have so far (the important parts)

```
  private void hideMessage(){
    byte[] messageBytes = message.getBytes();
    //message is a string
    int messageLength = messageBytes.length;
    for(int i = messageLength-1; i>=0; i--){
      imageBytes[i+100000] = messageBytes[i];
      //imageBytes is a bitmap image read into a byte array using imageIO
    }
  }
```

and

```
  private void getMessage(){
    int messageLength = 11;
    byte[] messageBytes = new byte[messageLength];
    for(int i = messageLength; i>0; i--){
      messageBytes[i-1] = imageBytes[i+10000];
    }
    message = new String(messageBytes);
  }
```

However this is the output I get for the string:

```
???????????
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Alex, I don't see how any of the code you posted would even compile...please clean this up.

Comment: @mre I'm printing it out using System.out.println(message);

Comment: @Martijn I'm using the +1000 to avoid writing the headers of the file. Otherwise it tells me it cannot read the file.

Comment: Are you manipulating the pure bytes of the image file, or the image data after decoding/before encoding?

Comment: @bemace thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to your zeroes. Your comment says 1000, `getMessage` uses 10000, and `hideMessage` uses 100000

(reposted as answer since apparently that's all that was wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply create a string from arbitrary bytes - the bytes must be encodings of characters in the encoding you are using (in your case, the default encoding). If you use bytes that don't map to a character, they will be mapped to `'?'`. The same is true in the other direction: If you have a string with characters which do not map to bytes, the `getBytes()` method will map them to `(byte)'?'`.  I think one or both of this happened here.

If you are using JPG or a similar lossy image format, it will change the bytes of your image during saving.

Comment: So I am using BMP which I believe is lossless. If I am converting the string to bytes by calling `message.getBytes();`  and retrieving it using new `String(messageBytes);` won't both use default encoding?

Comment: You are right, this is not the cause here (if not all of the characters are outside the representable range of your encoding). Still you better should define the encoding instead of relying on the default one.

Answer (score 1):

If the plan is to actually change part of your bitmap bytes, you'd need to export the image as png, as its lossless.  Jpeg would probably change the bytes slightly, which isn't a problem for an image, but for text its obviously critical.

Second, if you're going to pick 100,000 as a fixed position to insert the message, you should set that up as a constant to make it easier, and less error prone.  Speaking of which, your current fixed offsets are off by a '0', 10,000 and 100,000.

Answer (score 0):

But you should edit the raw file, but an instance of `BufferedImage`, then rewrite it back to a file with `ImageIO`.